# How to calculate the variability of proportions?

Tags: proportion, variability

I need to find the proper sample size, and I have found formula in the Stanford lectures. But I can’t understand what the “variability” of proportions means in this case.

Consider two proportions : 
P_hat = 1,2% 
P(1)_hat - P_hat = 0,2%[image]

Comment: For proportions, this is my guess without having access to the context: Under $H_0$ that the two proportions are equal one can find the pooled success probability $\bar p = (p_1+p_2)/2.$ Then the variance $p(1-p)$ of the null Bernoulli distribution is $\bar p(1-\bar p).$ If this makes no sense, then please provide more context.

Comment: Well, there is no other data provided. Thank you for your help

Comment: You can determine *any* moment of *any* binary distribution using the techniques and formulas at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/294737.  They indicate there is no difference in meaning of "variability" in the two settings: both refer to the variance $\sigma^2.$

Comment: Does it work for proportions too? And in my case what should I plug into formula?